# How to tell if indoor lemons are ready to pick

Tags: trees, indoors, fruits, lemons

I have an indoor lemon tree that has two lemons. It took a long time, but they finally turned yellow from green. How do I know when they are ready to pick?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pick them.  As you may have noticed, sometimes in the store they are yellow w/some green.  Some are picked when they are completely green, most are picked with some green. By the time they get to the store they are completely yellow or mostly yellow and ripe.  You've waited long enough.  ENJOY :)